# rollup hangs while building monorepo packages

Tags: node.js, typescript, apple-m1, es6-modules, rollup

I am using version 4.50 of Rollup and it hangs (never stops) while building SOMETIMES (~50%), but NOT always. ~50% of the time it builds all my packages quickly.

The main things I think might be specific to me are:

1. I use a monorepo, less than 40 packages.
2. Each package has its own `build: "rollup -c"` script.
3. Builds are launched via `npm run build -ws`
4. The build usually hangs between the 12th to 16th packages in the
   build order, and these consume ESM but emit CommonJS.

Config

- Output looks like

```js
{
  file: packageJson.main,
  format: "cjs",
  // format: "es",
  sourcemap: false,
  inlineDynamicImports: true,
}
```

- Plugins

```js
[
  json(),
  commonjs(),
  nodeResolve({ browser: false, exportConditions: ['node'] }),
  typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json", sourceMap: false }),
]
```

Sometimes I can work around the issue by building only that package, but sometimes even that hangs:

```
npm run build -w packages/the-one-that-hung
npm run build -ws # start over
```

I have NOT seen it hang when using Github Actions (default image) to build.

I am using:

1. Mac Sonoma 14.1.1 (23B81), Apple M1 Pro, with 32 GB.
2. node v18.17.1
3. npm 9.6.7
4. typescript 5.3.2

I have restarted my machine and minimized how many applications are running.
I build from the VSCode terminal with Oh-My-Zsh.